# binding textbox and slider without using angularjs only javascript

Tags: javascript, html, binding, slider

I
want
to
make
sure
that
the
echo
output
in
idMyEcho (textbox)
and
the
slider
position
on
idSlider (slider)
are
consistent
when
idButton (button)
is
pressed
and
when
the
user
changes
the
slider
bar

```js
var mCount = 0;
               incCount = function() {
                   mCount++;
                   var myEcho = document.getElementById("idMyEcho");
                   myEcho.setAttribute("value", mCount);
               };
               
               setCount = function() {
                   var aSlider = document.getElementById("idSlider");
                   mCount = aSlider.value;
               };
```

```html
<div>
            <input type="button" id="idButton" value="MyButton" onclick="incCount()">
            <input type="text" id="idMyEcho" value="0">
            <input type="range" id="idSlider" value="4" onclick="setCount()">
        </div>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few problems with your code, You should have $scope variable and controller ,

```
app.controller("testCtrl", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.mCount = 0;
    $scope.incCount = function() {
      $scope.mCount++;
    };

    $scope.setCount = function() {    
    };
  }
]);
```

**HTML**

```
  <div class="col-sm-12" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <div>
      <input type="button" id="idButton" value="MyButton" ng-click="incCount()">
      <input type="text" ng-model="mCount">
      <input type="range" id="idSlider" ng-model="mCount" ng-click="setCount()">
    </div>
  </div>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/qKUj5ylMjXAqUcgkCps2?p=preview)**

**[DEMO USING PURE JAVASCRIPT](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/3WdNd/58/)**

Comment: thanks. is there a way to do this without using angularsj and only javascript? if yes  how?

Comment: @stset why did you removeanswer?

Comment: in the last sample when you move the slider the textbox should be updated as well